# Python openCv contours

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to understand the ouput of [findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html) based on tutorials such as [this one](http://opencvpython.blogspot.com.br/2012/06/hi-this-article-is-tutorial-which-try.html) and the docs.I would like to know why I am getting the output I am getting.
I have a jpeg img with a square on the center and I am aiming to find the square and color it (just to understand better the contours functionality of openCv).
I am loading it like this:

```
# Load a colored image
img = cv2.imread('test_image.jpg')
#Make it gray
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#reducing noise
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,127,255,0)
#RETR_TREE make nested contours
#CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE    compresses horizontal, vertical, and diagonal segments and leaves only their end points.
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Now my image has a  square in the center with a 6px border.
It's outer border is roughly on (970,634), (1658,634), (1658,1328), (970,1328)

My problem is that the contours returned are the following 3:

#### The first one seems to be the whole image dimension

[[[   1    1]]

[[   1 3506]]

[[2478 3506]]

[[2478    1]]]

#### This one seems to have the square coordinates but with a dupplicate 1px diff on each point

[[[ 970  635]]

[[ 971  634]]

[[1658  634]]

[[1659  635]]

[[1659 1328]]

[[1658 1329]]

[[ 971 1329]]

[[ 970 1328]]]

#### The last one has the inner contours it seems

[[[ 977  641]]

[[ 977 1322]]

[[1652 1322]]

[[1652  641]]]

I am not understanding why these outputs are as they are, and did not find anything on the documentation regarding why I would get the full doc size for example.

Here is the image I am using [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the first one is the image contents and seem to always be given, the second one is the outer shape (don't know why so many points  and the small variation but is probably due to the find contours methid(
And the third one is the inner shape, the shape enclosed by the counter.
Basically here is what a full square image would be

[image]

Just the first match (the full image)

[image]

Just the second (outer square)

[image]

And the last one (inner square)

[image]